# % symbols keep printing when trying to print out a char 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, formatting

I'm new to C and I'm just trying to print out a two 2 array.
This bug has been annoying me all day and I'm not really sure whats going on.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void run(int);

main()
{
    run(5);
    return 0;
}

//Have to make it a character array as it needs to 
//store numbers AND commas. 
run(int x)
{
    int size = 2*x -1;
    char array[size][size];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for( i; i < size; i++){
        for(j; j< size; j++){
            array[i][j] = '1';
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    for( k; k < size; k++){
        for(l; l< size; l++){
            printf( "%c" , array[l][k]);
        }
        printf("%\n", "");
    } 
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
1%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
%
```

Comment: What are you expecting `printf("%\n", "")` to print? You don't have a formatting operator after `%`.

Comment: I was expecting just a new line to print - I guess I should just format that as a character then...

Comment: `for(j; j< size; j++){` - the `(j;` doesn't do anything, probably meant `for(j = 0; j< size; j++){`. Same problem with `l`, and similar (although harmless) with `i`  & `k`.

Comment: You should really learn how to use a debugger and step through your code. It will be the most important leasson you'll learn as a programmer.

Comment: @Amit Put it in an answer

Comment: @Barmar - did... took a while :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has several mistakes:

The biggest problem is that your not initializing your loop counters where you should:

```
for(i; i < size; i++){
  for(j; j < size; j++){
```

With that, `i` & `j` are left as they were prior to the `for` statement. The first section of these statements does nothing at all. While that's harmless for `i` (since it's initialized to 0 before the `for`), that's devastating for `j`, which never goes back to 0. Your code should be:

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
```

The same issue exists with `k` & `l`, and the same fix should be applied:

```
for(k = 0; k < size; k++){
  for(l = 0; l < size; l++){
```

---

Next, you're "rotating" access in your array. When you fill the array with values, you have `i` in your outer loop and `j` in the inner loop, and you use them as `[i][j]`:

```
array[i][j] = '1';
```

Think of that as `Out` & `In` --> `[Out][In]`.

When you print the array, you "rotate" that, `k` is outer & `l` is inner, and you use them as `[l][k]`:

```
printf("%c", array[l][k]);
```

That's like doing `[In][Out]`.
While that's not a problem with all values being identical (`'1'`), and the matrix being square (width == height), it won't work with other values or dimensions, and is confusing.

---

Last, you're attempt to print a new line is wrong. You have a `%` specifier, but your not really using any valid character after that, and you don't need that anyway, just print:

```
printf("\n");
```

---

So, all together, here's what the code should be:

```
run(int x)
{
    int size = 2*x -1;
    char array[size][size];
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
            array[i][j] = '1';
        }
    }

    int k, l;
    for(k = 0; k < size; k++){
        for(l = 0; l < size; l++){
            printf("%c", array[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } 
}
```

(And as a side note, `k` & `l` are not really required, you can simply reuse `i` & `j`)